# Line breaks on PRINTED version of html page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something like:

```
<div style = "white-space : pre-wrap;">
    long long long long text
    <br>
    long long long long text
    <br>
    long long long long text
</div>
```

Now I want to PRINT this html in Mozilla Firefox 53.0.3

I press File->Print preview and select, for example, 120% scale (I want to print with font size, comfortable to my eyes).

BUT - it seems, that text in "print preview" is cropped due to A4 page size:

```
long long long
long long long
long long long
```

And I want to see:

```
long long long
text
long long long
text
long long long
text
```

I tried many-many styles like "white-space", "word-wrap", "overflow" and so on, but no one could help me.
So can I do this beautiful task?

Comment: rather than scaling up, could you use print-only CSS (via media queries) to change the font size? Then that might avoid the overflow problem, which could be due to scaling up. Also I suspect it maybe isn't cropped as such but just goes onto the next printed page? Again using print-only CSS you could attempt to set an appropriate width as well.